# Issue keeping upper and lower case intact

Tags: case, case-sensitive

I use following php to display any part of a URL:

```
<?php
$segments = explode('/', trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));
$numSegments = count($segments); 
$currentSegment1 = $segments[$numSegments - 1];
$currentSegment2 = $segments[$numSegments - 2];
$currentSegment3 = $segments[$numSegments - 3];
$currentSegment4 = $segments[$numSegments - 4];
?>

<?php echo $currentSegment1;?>
```

Problem is it converts all to lower case:
http://example.com/ABCDefgh

It displays abcdefgh instead of ABCDefgh, which is a problem since I use it for embedding youtube videos where video ID is case sensitive.

My question: Is there any way the script can keep upper and lower case intact?

Thanks!

Comment: Other php scripts I found here which display last part of an URL  have the same issue: they convert all to lower case.